# Define a function which assigns employees to the nearest workstation

Tags: python, class

First of all, I'm very new to python programming, so please bear with me.
I'm trying to write a very simple code that assigns employees to the nearest workstation.

For this purpose, I created two classes, one `Employee` class and one `Workstation` class. Their attributes are basically the same, they both have a name and a location (the `location` attribute is represented by integers in order to keep it simple). The `Employee` class also has an additional attribute called `workstation` which is set to `"not_assigned_yet"` by default.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
class Workstation:

  def __init__(self, name, location):
      self.name=name
      self.location=location

W1=Workstation("Workstation1", 0)
W2=Workstation("Workstation2", 5)

class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, location,workstation):
        self.name=name
        self.location=location
        self.workstation=workstation

E1=Employee("Employee1", 3, "not_assigned_yet")
E2=Employee("Employee2", 6, "not_assigned_yet" )
```

What I would like to do is define a method for the `Employee` class which finds the `Workstation` with the nearest location for the `Employee` object and assigns the `Employee` to that workstation

For example, if I was to assign `E1` to its nearest workstation, the result would more or less look like this:

```
E1.workstation=W1.name
```

So how do I put that into universal code?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: He, Reinhart, first of all you definitely need some type of DB, or global variable for each Workstation data, after this when you will be able to choose for you Employee nearest Workstation.  Also you can check code to find nearest integer
[link](https://repl.it/repls/DirtyFickleMicrostation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help guys. I eventually figured out the problem with the help of arnaldocan and JEX.
First I used the min() function suggested by JEX for finding the closest workstation (I had to create a list (W) containing the different locations of all workstations first).

```
 def assign(self):
        a= (min(W, key=lambda x: abs(x-self.location)))
```

Then I followed arnaldocans advise and iterated over the list of all Workstations (WW), if the integer with the closest workstation is in that list, the employee's location takes over its name:

```
def assign(self):
    a= (min(W, key=lambda x: abs(x-self.location)))
    for w in WW:
        if a==w.location:
            self.workstation=w.name
    print(self.workstation)
```

Thats pretty much all. I created 3  workstations and 3 employees with different locations. When I run the method , every employee is assigned to the closest workstation.Heres the full code:

```
class Workstation:

    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name=name
        self.location=location

W1=Workstation("Workstation1", 0)
W2=Workstation("Workstation2",10)
W3=Workstation("Workstation3", 5)

W = [W1.location, W2.location, W3.location]
WW=[W1, W2, W3]

class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, location,workstation):
        self.name=name
        self.location=location
        self.workstation=workstation


    def assign(self):
        a= (min(W, key=lambda x: abs(x-self.location)))
        for w in WW:
            if a==w.location:
                self.workstation=w.name
        print(self.workstation)


E1=Employee("Employee1", 9, "not_assigned_yet")
E2=Employee("Employee2", 7, "not_assigned_yet" )
E3=Employee("Employee3", 2, "not_assigned_yet" )

E1.assign()
E2.assign()
E3.assign()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use arrays (or dictionaries). So, your code will look like:

```
W = []
W.append(W1)
W.append(W2)
E = []
E.append(E1)
E.append(E2)
```

Second, you can just iterate over employers and then over workstation to find the best matches:

```
import math
for e in E:
  closest_distance = math.inf
  closest_workstation = ""
  for w in W:
    diff = abs(w.location - e.location)
    if diff < closest_distance:
      closest_distance = diff
      closest_workstation = w
  e.workstation = closest_workstation.name

for e in E:
  print(e.workstation)
```

If you wish to, it is possible to convert the snippet above in a method for employee class. This could be recommend (Active Record) or discouraged (DAO) according to the design patterns you adhere to.